# Spring MVC: Howto get the fragment of an URL by a Controller Method

Tags: java, spring, url, spring-mvc

Consider the following URL:

http://www.iamsomeweiredurl.fromsomewhere/andIwant#thisfragment

Is there a chance to get "thisfragment" by `@RequestMapping` or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You have to use JavaScript to get anchors.